# Use second element of a split string in LINQ where query

Tags: c#, linq

Is the following possible: Retrieve all last name that starts with a p using LINQ. But the first name and last name is one word separated by a space.
Example would be Jonh Peter. Luke Sam, Rock Papers,Lee P

I tried the following:

```
var result = test.Where(x => x.Owner.Split(' ')[1]
                 .ToLowerInvariant()
                 .StartsWith("p")
             );
```

Comment: What result did you get from the example code?

Comment: {"Index was outside the bounds of the array."} but [0] or first works in the since no errors but not the correct result

Comment: Why are you calling `ToString()` on a string?

Comment: are you familiar with case sensitivity `.StartsWith("p")` I would think that one would use the `.ToUpper()` on that also do a google search on the `.Split()` method and look at it's overloads and how to use it

Comment: Not for nothing, but are you allergic to accepting answers?

Comment: It's only been 6 minutes. Take it easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or just

```
var result = test.Where(x => x.IndexOf(" P", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Split('')` is not a split by space. use: `Split(' ')`

And you can remove `ToString()` it is redundant code because `Split(' ')[1]` has already returned a string